# How can I drop a branch from a mulitple branch merger in git?

Tags: git, merge, revert

I just merged three different branches together as part of a feature set and pushed the results so that the repository tree currently looks like the following:

```
--- A --- A1 --- A2 --- A3 --
    |                         \
    + --- B1 --- B2 --- B3 --- B4-
    |                              \
    + --- C1 --- C2 --- C3 ---------C4
```

However, I have just been told that the `B` branch as not ready for prime time so I need to undo those commits. How can I roll back my changes so that my new head `C5` would be a merger of the `C3` and `A3` commits? When I am done I want the repository to look like the following:

```
    + --- B1 --- B2 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5
    |                         /
--- A --- A1 --- A2 --- A3 --
    |                         \
    + --- C1 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- C5
```

Comment: Why don't you just hard reset all branches to 3rd state and do merge with A from B and C? Do you you mean you already did some extra work after this fail-merge and would like to fix this merge while preserving following work?

Comment: @the.malkolm - In some cases I think that might be the case, one of the developers was asking about how remove some feature code that not going to be released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# checkout before merge
git checkout C3
# make merge we want
git merge A3
# rebase any work on top of the new merge
git rebase --onto HEAD C4 branch_C
# use fixed version as branch_C
git branch -f branch_C HEAD
# aha! now you on the fixed branch_C
git checkout branch_C
```

Than do exactly the same with B. I suppose you didn't branch C & B further after 'bad' merge.

Answer (score 3):

I'm from the camp that prefers redoing botch ups *as long as it hasn't been pushed*, to leave a less verbose history and I usually do so like this:

```
# go back to commit C3
git checkout C3

# redo the merge with only A
git merge branch_A

# make sure you've gotten the desired alteration
# git diff --stat branch_C
# git diff branch

# switch your C branch over to your redone version
git checkout -B branch_C

# otherwise if you change your mind, just go back to C4
# git checkout branch_C
```

**Edit:** Comment #4 was entirely correct in that the previous version of this resulted in nothing.  This edit changes the `git merge` line, which was previously merging `B4`.  The `--detach` option from the initial checkout was also removed as it's superfluous if the argument `C3` isn't a branch name.

Comment: There's really no reason to expect that there's a branch at C3. In fact everything indicates otherwise: in the picture, C3 represents a commit. So your use of `--detach` is an unnecessary distraction.

Comment: That's true. But my use of `--detach` is more about explicity in my advice and I think its use above has these advantages: 1. It hints on the notion of using detached states, which is similar but subtly different from using `git checkout` on a branch. 2. If I don't explicitly say something along those lines, someone less familiar might think specifying branch names are synonymous, then end up in confusion after moving it. (Although on second thoughts, these same people probably don't create arbitrary branches..)

Comment: The point is that, while it's a good thing to know about, this isn't really a good way to show what it means or why you'd need to use it, because you're using it in a situation where it's a no-op.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your walk through doesn't actually result in a code base that is a merger of `A3` and `C3` without the `B3` code. What I want is the head of the `C` branch to be the `A3` and `C3`, unless that is the case I have to downvote this answer as it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Revert C4 (and commit that reversion), then merge A3 into the C5 you just created.

```
--- A --- A1 --- A2 --- A3 -----------------------------
    |                         \                          \
    + --- B1 --- B2 --- B3 --- B4-                        \
    |                              \                       \
    + --- C1 --- C2 --- C3 ---------C4--- C5(reverts C4) -- C6
```

You end up with B4 containing B3 + A3, and C6 containing C3 + A3.

I imagine you could do all this by rebasing too, but I prefer to leave my tracks when I've done something messy, so I can see both my mistake and what I did to fix it. Rebase undoes history, which makes me twitch.

Comment: Would it then just be a matter of reverting to `B3` and committing to undo the `B4` commit if need be?

Comment: Revert doesn't "undo" a commit exactly. You don't "revert to" an earlier one. Reverting a commit creates a NEW commit that is the INVERSE of the specified commit, backing out the CHANGE, while moving FORWARD in time. So: to undo the B4 commit, you'd revert B4, and then commit that, on that branch. See http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/16/rolling-back-changes-with-revert.html  `git reset` moves you backward in time, sort of like rebase, but I prefer to revert and keep a track record of my error and my fix.

Comment: Reverting merges is... interesting. Read the manpage, under the `-m` option, including the warning that subsequent merges won't bring back the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't *shared* this repository with anyone else yet, you can try [`git rebase --onto`](http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html).

```
git rebase --onto <to> <from> <what>
```

I'll assume your branches are named A (at A3), B (at B4) and C (at C4):

```
git rebase --onto B3 A3 C
```

Where B3 and A3 are actually the commit SHAs themselves.

I **strongly** recommend backing up your repository before executing this command to play it on the safe side, though.